# How to use sub features of angular-ui-bootstrap with JSPM?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, jspm

Of course, it's unnecessary to load the entire angular-ui-bootstrap library (~500k with templates, tpls) just to use a few features.

I only need the dropdown and the popover (for now).

Using JSPM, how can I make a dependency for that feature alone, or reference the [custom-built](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) file I've made ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A direct solution:**

You can use the standard module syntax to import components directly from the modules in which they are defined.  For those components:

```
import 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/dropdown/index.js';
import 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/popover/index.js';
```

**A more naive / better solution:**

JSPM 0.17 (currently in beta as of 2016-02-29) utilizes [Rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup) in its build tool which performs tree-shaking to reduce the footprint of your dependencies.  I haven't experimented yet to see how effective this is out of the box in wrangling CommonJS modules.

Comment: Took your direct solution for now. Thanks! You should update your answer with module dependency not "ui.bootstap" anymore, but rather the used modules only; "ui.bootstrap.dropdown" and "ui.bootstrap.popover".

Comment: ahh sorry, "ui.bootstrap.module.dropdown" and "ui.bootstrap.module.popover".

Comment: I think that you might be confusing the module names that angular uses with the ES6 module names/paths that JSPM uses.  JSPM unfortunately can't make sense of what angular refers to as a 'module'.
I should qualify my answer to explain that for angular tree-shaking is probably not possible (/effective) when importing the library's main module because use of components isn't statically analyzable.